# Flex 4: Scrolling a Spark Form to focussed element programatically?

Tags: apache-flex, forms, flex4.5, vertical-scrolling, scroller

I found this example http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/02/auto-scrolling-the-contents-of-a-vgroup-container-in-flex-4/ which works great but only if you have the focussable elements in a VGroup.

However I have a Form inside the VGroup which means that the focussable elements are in FormItems of the Form. The Form can't be added directly into the Scroller and doesn't have a layout property.

I could use form.getElementIndex(formItem) and then do some math using the formItem y position but that's very ugly. Anyone have an idea how to get this working in a clean way like the above example?

Comment: Woot woot! I just found Scroller.ensureElementIsVisible()! Nevermind! :D

Comment: If you figured it out; please answer your own question and select your own answer as such.  This will help people in the future who stumble upon the question.

Comment: Yup, tried it yesterday but didn't have the SO privilege to do that. Seems today  it works.

Answer (score 2):

Woot woot! I just found Scroller.ensureElementIsVisible()! Nevermind! :D